# Google OAuth2: Asking for no information (empty scope)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

**Is it possible to ask for no information when connecting with a google account with OAuth2 ?**

I tried to pass an empty `scope` parameter but It won't work (Usual google error page).

Also, there is no list of the available parameters for `scope`...For now I use `scope=email`.

Edit: A list of scope parameters I finally found: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, you cant.

As [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3) says:

> If the client omits the scope parameter when requesting authorization, the authorization server MUST either process the request using a pre-defined default value or fail the request
> indicating an invalid scope.

And Google's implementation chooses the later one.